# Taxicab distance in ios app

Tags: ios, minesweeper

Im making an ios game very similar to minesweeper in terms of layout and i have no clue how to do taxicab distance. Do I need to use core graphics or just an array or what?

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) .

In essence, the taxicab distance between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is `|x1-x2| + |y1-y2|` (|z| means abs(z))

Answer (score 0):

My approach would have been to use a two-dimensional array - it just seems the simplest and most natural representation of the problem.

I would set all values of the array to 0, randomize and reset certain indices to -1 (mines), and increment the count of each adjacent square of these indices by 1.